# R using multiple keys in 2 dataframe get value acoordingly

Tags: r, key

first Dataframe looks like following with many rows:

| id | sub_id | name_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1b1 | 3 |
| 1 | a2b1 | 4 |
| 2 | a3b1 | 3 |
| 2 | a3b1 | 2 |
| 3 | a3b2 | 2 |
| 3 | a4b1 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

second Dataframe looks like following with many columns:

| id | top_name_id_1 | top_name_id_2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | ... |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | ... |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | ... |

the new dataframe should look like:

| id | sub_id_1 | sub_id_2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a2b1 | a1b1 | ... |
| 2 | a3b1 | a3b1 | ... |
| 3 | a3b2 | a4b1 | ... |

so the third df[,2:n] basically is replaced with sub_id in df1 by matching the combination of id and name_id from df1, and id and top_name_ids in df2.

Comment: Please frame this in the form of a question, and include code and research that you've attempted so far. As it stands, I fell compelled to say that SO is not a free-code service. If you haven't done any research yet, look at `merge`, specifically two calls. Try to create `sub_id_1` first, and once you've done that, do almost the same thing to bring in `sub_id_2`. (Another candidate function would be `left_join`.)

Comment: Thanks, I combined 2 entities into one unique column, it works well.